# Laravel Return Value from Controller via JS Get Method

Tags: html, css, laravel, axios

I am trying to create a Request via Axios JS to the API Route and trying to send the data from the database over the controller back to the view of the page. When I am just put an string as return value it is working.
I am always getting following a 500 Error.

JS File

```
function getSelectedItem() {
    var e = document.getElementById("Objekt");
    if (e.value > 0) {
        axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/api/zimmer/' + e.value,
                responseType: 'stream'
            })
            .then(function(response) {

                zimmer_select.disabled = false;
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });


    } else {
        zimmer_select.disabled = true;
    }
    console.log(e.value);
}
```

API Route:

```
Route::controller(MieterController::class)->group(function () {
Route::get('/zimmer/{id}', 'relocate_update')->name('api.get.zimmer');
```

});

Controller:

```
public function relocate_update($id) {
    $zimmer_zu_objekt = Zimmer::findOrFail()->where('objekt_id', $id);
    return response()->json(['alle_zimmer' => $zimmer_zu_objekt], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I changed it to VanillaJS and the main problem was my Eloquent Query in the Controller. Corret is

```
return Zimmer::where('objekt_id','=', $id)->get();
```

and used the fetch-method is JS:

```
fetch('/api/zimmer/' + e.value)
            .then(function(response) {
                zimmer_select.disabled = false;
                console.log(response.json());
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```